# Render HTML with CSS in Java

Tags: java, html, css

I'm trying to display HTML in my java application that has a linked stylesheet include in my HTML.

I am transforming my XML to HTML using XSLT from Java.  I want to include a stylesheet so I can easily style the html output.  However the stylesheet is being ignored and the html is being output normally.

To do this I am using a JEditorPane and HTMLEditorKit.  I found some sample code on [Dev Daily](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-create-simple-swing-html-viewer-browser-java) to do this.

My stylesheet is sitting on my local hard drive and I wondered if anyone knew how I could use it?

I have the following code:

```
JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
jEditorPane.setEditable( false );

HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
jEditorPane.setEditorKit(kit);

try {    
    kit.getStyleSheet().importStyleSheet( new URL( "file://D:\\mycssfile.css" ) );
} catch( MalformedURLException ex ) {
}

Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
jEditorPane.setDocument(doc);
jEditorPane.setText(html);
```

In my html output from xsl the css is linked using the following - I get the same result with it included or excluded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Andez

Comment: I think HTMLEditorKit has fairly poor support for CSS, that could be the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL isn't valid, so it can't find your CSS file. Change it to:

```
kit.getStyleSheet().importStyleSheet(new URL("file:///D:/mycssfile.css"));
```

Or better still, instead of using a URL, add the css file to your classpath and then load it as a resource, like this:

```
kit.getStyleSheet().importStyleSheet(MyClassName.class.getResource("mycssfile.css"));
```

Comment: I went for the kit.getStyleSheet().importStyleSheet(new URL("file:///D:/mycssfile.css")); option.  Our configuration is stored relatively under the java application path so just need to figure that part out.